# Fail to copy and insert the data in mysql after clicking the button

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create the button, so the user can click it. When they click, the data from the database will be copied from table1 to table2. 
This is my error:
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id='15' SELECT id,q FROM table1 WHERE id='15'' at line 1")

My code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (id,q) WHERE id=%s SELECT id,q FROM table1 WHERE id=%s", (id,id))
```

Plz help me...Thank you

Comment: ```Insert``` does not work with ```where``` clause. You have to remove ```where``` clause from ```insert```

Comment: I have tried do it but got error also, example: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: What exactly did you tried to execute. Update the question with that along with full error message.

Comment: Already updated.. U got it? Sorry for my mistake

Comment: No, i meant the query which you tried without the ```where``` clause

Comment: This is my updated code:                                                              cur.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (id,q) SELECT id,q FROM table1 WHERE id=%s", (id,id))

Comment: The error that I got is MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Insert statement is Wrong.
You can't have `WHERE` in your `INSERT`
Try This:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table2 (id,q) SELECT id,q FROM table1 WHERE id=%s", (id))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with python but your sql has wrong syntax . put a ; before select . why don't you use that function seperately for insert and once again for select ???

Comment: Will try to do it... Tq